# Convert excel to R, calculating from previous row, slow loop

Tags: r, excel, performance, loops

I have some data that has been decoded and looks as follows:

```
datetime    date - day  date - month  date - year  gmt hrs  gmt minutes  gmt seconds  val1  val2  val3
37:00.9         NULL        NULL          15          0        30          54         1      1     0
37:01.9          29          9           NULL   0   30  55  1   1   0
37:02.9         NULL        NULL         NULL   0   30  56  1   1   0
37:03.9         NULL        NULL         NULL   0   30  57  1   1   0
37:04.9         NULL        NULL          15    0   30  58  1   1   0
37:05.9          29          9           NULL   0   30  59  1   1   0
37:06.9         NULL        NULL         NULL   0   31  0   1   1   0
37:07.9         NULL        NULL         NULL   0   31  1   1   1   0
37:08.9         NULL        NULL          15    0   31  2   1   1   0
37:09.9          29          9           NULL   0   31  3   1   1   0
37:10.9         NULL        NULL         NULL   0   31  4   1   1   0
37:11.9         NULL        NULL         NULL   0   31  5   1   1   0
37:12.9         NULL        NULL          15    6   7   40  1   1   0
37:13.9          30          9           NULL   6   7   41  1   1   0
37:14.9         NULL        NULL         NULL   6   7   42  1   1   0
37:15.9         NULL        NULL         NULL   6   7   43  1   1   0
37:16.9         NULL        NULL          15    6   7   44  1   1   0
```

datetime is merely the time at decode so isn't relevant, and we see there are many NULL values in the date columns. You can also see that the time does have gaps as seen in the gmt change between the dates 29th and 30th. I would like to replace NULLs with the correct dates. For day, in excel I wrote the following (in K3):

`=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B3)=FALSE,OR(G3=G2+1,F3=F2+1,E3=E2+1,G3=G2,G3=G2+2)),K2,IF(ISNUMBER(B3)=FALSE,MAX(B4,B5,B6),B3))`

Note sometimes seconds is equal to the row before and sometimes the diff is 2 seconds, which is why the `OR` covers those as well.

This works well, but the files are too large for excel to handle well. So I loaded these files into data tables in R and wrote the following equivalent code (doesnt cover the max part but added that after this failed):

```
test2$day =ifelse(is.na(test2$`DATE - DAY`)==T &
 (test2$`GMT SECONDS`==shift(test2$`GMT SECONDS`)+1 |test2$`GMT SECONDS`== shift(test2$`GMT SECONDS`) | test2$`GMT SECONDS`==shift(test2$`GMT SECONDS`)+2
  | test2$`GMT MINUTES`== shift(test2$`GMT MINUTES`) +1 
   | test2$`GMT HRS`==shift(test2$`GMT HRS`) +1  ),
  shift(test2$day), ifelse(is.na(test2$`DATE - DAY`)==T, shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`, type = 'lead'),test2$`DATE - DAY`))
```

> Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok] : 
>     replacement has length zero
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
>     'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL

The above failed, so I created the following loop:

```
 if(nrow(test3)>1) for(i in 2:nrow(test3)) test3$day[i]= ifelse(is.na(test3$`DATE - DAY`[i])==T &
          (test3$`GMT SECONDS`[i]==(test3$`GMT SECONDS`[i-1])+1 |test3$`GMT SECONDS`[i]== (test3$`GMT SECONDS`[i-1]) | test3$`GMT SECONDS`[i]==(test3$`GMT SECONDS`[i-1])+2
          | test3$`GMT MINUTES`[i]== (test3$`GMT MINUTES`[i-1]) +1 
           | test3$`GMT HRS`[i]==(test3$`GMT HRS`[i-1]) +1 ),
          test3$day[i-1], ifelse(is.na(test3$`DATE - DAY`[i])==T, max(test3$`DATE - DAY`[i+1],test3$`DATE - DAY`[i+2],test3$`DATE - DAY`[i+3], na.rm=T),test3$`DATE - DAY`[i]))
```

This loop works, but it is quite slow. My test data frame is 80K rows and the loop took about 10min, but I will be dealing with data frames with a few million rows. I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this in R.

Hopefully this makes sense, essentially the code is saying if the day is NULL (NA when in R), if the time follows from the row before then use the last date from the row above. If the time changes, choose the next date from one of the next 4 rows.

I cannot change the decoder, and I tried a few imputation methods including using averages, regression and kNN and none seemed to work well so a logical rule like the above is best. It is just slow in loops.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Try this `library(zoo); 
na.locf(d$´date - day´)`

Comment: na.locf doesn't work because the way the different dates join each other. Each date 'block' has the same pattern of 3 nulls between each date, but where the 'block' starts in that pattern isnt always the same. Thats why I wrote a rule based on the GMT otherwise it would be fairly trivial

Comment: expected output is either a new column with the correct date value for each row, or replacing the NULL with the correct date in the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I wrote some logic that handles all the problems I had:

```
test2$time = strptime(sprintf("%s:%s:%s", test$`GMT HRS`, test$`GMT MINUTES`, test$`GMT SECONDS`), "%H:%M:%S")

test2$time = as.POSIXct(test2$time)

test2$day = ifelse(is.na(test2$`DATE - DAY`)==T & abs(test2$time - shift(test2$time)) < 3, 
                       ifelse(is.na(shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`))==F,shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`), ifelse(is.na(shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`, n=2))==F, shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`, n=2), shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`, n=3))),
                       ifelse(is.na(test2$`DATE - DAY`) == T, 
                      ifelse(is.na(shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`, type="lead"))==F,shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`, type="lead"), ifelse(is.na(shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`, n=2, type="lead"))==F, 
                    shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`, n=2, type="lead"), shift(test2$`DATE - DAY`, n=3, type="lead"))),
                              test2$`DATE - DAY`))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. I added all helper-columns to the data.frame to illustrate what's going on. Of course you can also use base R instead of the dplyr writings. I decided that a >2 minutes difference defines a new day.
(`V2=date - day`;`V6=gmt minutes`)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

d %>% 
  mutate(V2=ifelse(V2=="NULL",NA, V2),
         day=na.locf(V2, na.rm=F)) %>% 
  mutate(diff=c(0,diff(V6)),
         day2=dplyr::lead(day),
         day_final=ifelse(abs(diff)>2, day2, day))
```